# I have EU settled status. How can I ensure I can return to the UK within a short time, if my details change while abroad?

Tags: united-kingdom, names, eu-settlement-scheme

I am an EU citizen who has lived in the UK for more than a decade. When the settlement scheme became available, I applied and got approved for settled status.

Within the next year, I plan to change my name in the country I am a citizen in. In order to do this, I will most likely have to be in that country and will need to return to the UK under a different passport and a different name than the one they have on file.

According to the website, in order to change my name in the settlement scheme I will have to send them my passport (the original) and wait for it to be returned:

> Because your personal details have changed, you need to send us an identity document that shows your new personal details by post. This must be a valid passport, national identity card, or biometric residence card or permit. […]
>
> You must send us the actual identity document with your new personal details on it, not a copy. […]
>
> You will get an email when your account has been updated, or if there is a problem.
>
> Your identity document will be returned by recorded delivery to the postal address on your account, or you can give us a preferred return address on the cover sheet.
>
> The new document will be added to your account and you will need to use these document details to sign in.

There is no timeframe mentioned and I fear this could take weeks or longer, while I don't intend my visit to the country to be longer than a week or two (nor can I be absent from work for that long). Only the bare minimum to make the change and produce identity documents.

It also does not make clear whether they will accept to return the passport to an address outside the UK.

Any identity document I currently have will be invalid after the change, and of course I will not be able to send one that doesn't yet exist.

How could I make this change while abroad, and return to the UK afterwards?

Comment: You would need to inquire this, but you might be able to enter with a new passport under a new name, plus an older invalidated passport with an old name (that would have been valid if you hadn’t changed your name) and settled status details that match your old passport. Obviously enquire first if this works.

Comment: For many purposes, an embassy or consulate of your country in the Uk might be able to do the same things. That would be another enquiry. And assuming you are not the first one, they might know what to do.

Comment: I found out that any EU citizen is allowed to be in the UK for up to 6 months and are normally not checked at the border, so my current plan is to enter this way when it happens and update settlement scheme afterwards. I'll add it as a reply when it happens and I've confirmed it's fine.